# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DECIMAL128 mongoDB spark

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark

I'm writing a spark job using `pyspark`; I should only read from `mongoDB` collection and print the content on the screen; the code is the following:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp").config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/marco.weather_test").config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/marco.out").getOrCreate()

df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/marco.weather_test").load()

#df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

the problem is that when I want to print the schema the job works, but when I want to print the content of the dataFrame with `show()` function I get back the error:

```
#java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DECIMAL128
```

the command I use is:

```
#bin/spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.3 /home/erca/Scrivania/proveTesi/test_batch.py
```

Comment: Anyone ever found the solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error due to wrong jar is used for mongo-java-driver. 
The NoSuchFieldError is raised from

> org.bson.BsonType.Decimal128

, and the field Decimal128 is added in class BsonType after mongo-java-driver 3.4。While the

> org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.4

contains mongo-java-driver 3.6.2, a existing jar "mongo-java-driver" with version 3.2.1 is located in driverExtraClassPath.

Just start the spark-shell with verbose:

> spark-shell --verbose

i.e. the output:

```
***
***
Parsed arguments:
  master                  local[*]
  deployMode              null
  executorMemory          1024m
  executorCores           1
  totalExecutorCores      null
  propertiesFile          /etc/ecm/spark-conf/spark-defaults.conf
  driverMemory            1024m
  driverCores             null
  driverExtraClassPath    /opt/apps/extra-jars/*
  driverExtraLibraryPath  /usr/lib/hadoop-current/lib/native
***
***
```

and pay attention to the `driverExtraClassPath`, `driverExtraLibraryPath`.

Check these paths, and remove `mongo-java-driver` if it exists within these paths.

Answer (score 0):

Importing the library explicitly might solve the issue or give you a better error message for debugging.

`import org.bson.types.Decimal128`

Answer (score 0):

To BSON jar I a dded a version major and it worked

(In gradle)

```
compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'bson', version: '3.10.2',  'force': "true"
```